# Android Studio : Gradle sync failed: Could not download tink

Tags: kotlin, gradle, tink

When start a project on Android Studio 4.0, Gradle cannot sync completely and Design mode is unavailable. Error message appear - > Gradle sync failed: Could not download tink-1.3.0-rc2.jar (com.google.crypto.tink:tink:1.3.0-rc2): No cached version available for offline mode

Answer (score 3):

[Click on gradle tab and toggle the offline mode off as shown below, it solves the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYunU.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you are not sure if you have a problem with the Internet, go to the address installation path
**G:\Users\anythings\AndroidStudioProjects\anythings**
 Go and delete the folder named **.gradel** and re-run the program after you are sure the internet connection is connected.

*Important: If you are in a country that is under sanctions, be sure to use a vpn or circumvention beforehand.